# Can't trigger mouseenter programmatically in MooTools

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mootools

I'm writing unit tests and I need to trigger a mouseenter to make sure the handler is attached to a certain element and it does the right things in the callback. However, I spent a bunch of time on it and realized it seems just to be mouse events... I think. http://jsbin.com/EZIriqA/1/edit

It should fire two alerts. One for "double click" and one for "mouse enter". It only fires one. The code is identical (I made sure by copying and pasting it and just changing the event names).

Here's the code:

```
$('foo').addEvent('mouseenter:relay(li[data-type])', function () {
  alert('Mouse Enter');
});

$('foo').fireEvent('mouseenter', {
  target: $$('li[data-type]')[0]
});

$('foo').addEvent('dblclick:relay(li[data-type])', function () {
  alert('Double Click');
});

$('foo').fireEvent('dblclick', {
  target: $$('li[data-type]')[0]
});
```

How would I go about testing code in mouseenters if I can't get it to trigger? I can move all the code around to being methods on the class assign them here, but I didn't write this code and reason I'm writing unit tests is to safely refactor all of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: drunk. but: this is because mootools kind of pioneered `mouseenter` (along with prototype) before it was a native event. `mouseenter` is actually extending `mouseover` in the polyfill. delegated `mouseenter` is actually not a good practice - it has been buggy and is considered a better idea to use `mouseover:relay()` instead.

This was added recently-ish (1.4.4/5) - https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Element/Element.Event.js#L156-L162 - `Element.NativeEvents.mouseenter = 2;` bit. Not sure it has worked on the delegator level yet.

Anyway - because `mouseenter` has `mouseover` as base, you can `parentel.fireEvent('mouseover', { target: el })` and it will be fine.

I know this is pseudo code but you still don't seem to be using mootools as per best practices.

```
document.id('the-sandbox').set('html', '<ul id="foo"><li data-type="foo">Foo</li><li data-type="bar">Bar</li></ul>');
var t = document.getElement('li[data-type]'),
    foo = document.id('foo');

foo.addEvents({
  'mouseenter:relay(li[data-type])': function () {
    console.log('Mouse Enter'); 
  },
  'dblclick:relay(li[data-type])': function () { 
    console.log('Double Click');
  }  
});

foo.fireEvent('mouseover', { 
  target: t
}).fireEvent('dblclick', {
  target: t
});
```

differences: even though $ returns an el, use the element api. new Elements / prime selectors won't return an element, will be wrapped. selectors should be cached. $$ should be cached but is better to use `document.getElement` -> `querySelector` vs `$$` -> `querySelectorAll()[0]`.

Also, if you want to do tests of these, I suggest something like Syn (synthetic event library, on github) - it's really like a mini web-driver that you can tell to mouseover, click, type etc. very handy if you don't mind crossing testing boundaries between unit and end2end / integration testing.

Comment: Haha :) And still with that disclaimer you can give such detailed answer... impressive & +1!

Comment: "I know this is pseudo code but you still don't seem to be using mootools as per best practices." -- yes, that code wasn't copy pasted. I just typed it up for stackoverflow as an example :) Thanks so much! Totally working now.

Comment: I know __you__ do - but others will read this code and copy/paste it into their own app :)